# Regex find procedures exec without named parameters

Tags: python, regex, t-sql

I'm creating a T-SQL script validation file so they follow standards.
I need a regex, which will be executed in python that identifies executions of procedures without the explicit indication of the parameters.

Right:

```
exec schema.sp_procedure_name @parameterOne = 1, @parameter2 = 2
@parameter3 = 3, @parameter4 = 4
```

or

```
exec schema.sp_procedure_name
@parameterOne = 1, 
@parameter2 = 2
@parameter3 = 3,
@parameter4 = 4
```

Wrong:

```
exec schema.sp_procedure_name 1, 2, 3, 4
```

or

```
exec schema.sp_procedure_name2
1,
2,
3,
4
```

I need to identify what is wrong, so the regex should match in the second case, I've read some manuals, handouts and regex forums, but I still can not get to a thought to be able to create such an expression, I have managed to get to that so far, But you do not answer me yet:

```
(exec(ute)?\s*\w+\.\w+\s*)(\w+\s*\,|.*\w+\s*\,)
```

Can you help me with a functional code and explain why it works? Taking into consideration that things can come in broken lines, as in the examples above, or all on the same line

Answer (score 0):

This is a start, but this is actually a really hard problem.

This regex is a start:

```
exec(ute)?\s+\S+\s+[^@]

exec(ute)?
\s+ whitespace
\S+ non-whitespace
\s+ whitespace
[^@]  - any character that is not @
```

This will only check that the first parameter is an "@"

It could also fail if someone put a space like   "schema.   procedurename", which I think is valid SQL.  People could also probably screw it up by putting comments in the SQL.

Comment: thx, but still does not help me, I need to check all parameters, regarding comments, are removed before doing this check

Comment: I don't think you are going to solve this with regex.  You either need a full-blown sql parser ( complicated ), or maybe to make it a manual code review process.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm going to break my head a little bit with this, thanks for now!